# Jest can't resolve import with @ (at) character

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

I have a problem. When I run **Jest** tests it can't resolve my imports with at (`@`) signs. I have an error:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@/helpers/configureStore' from 'App.js'
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [in this post](https://alexjover.com/blog/enhance-jest-configuration-with-module-aliases/). So according to the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) we should go to our `package.json` file, and make sure our config contains something like:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
       "@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  }
}
```

`"@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"` that's a cool regex which will resolve our  `@/helpers/configureStore` to `src/helpers/configureStore`.

Also remember to quit from **jest** interactive mode (with `q` key) and run it again to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a jest.config.ts and importing something like '@app/app.constants' you can replace

```
   moduleNameMapper: {},
```

with

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
  },
```